# Bought Wacom Intuos4 for teaching through online videos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, sketching, artboard, autodesk-sketchbook-pro

It came with Photoshop 10 Express, Autocad SketchBook Express and Corel Painter Sketch Pad. They all seem like great tools for creating/modifying art and photos. Is there a better application for drawing using the Wacom Intuos4 for the purpose of teaching, like they do at Khan Academy?

Comment: Maybe look for some kind of presentation/whiteboard app? OpenOffice Impress might work.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer. First of all, none of these bring any features to the table, when it comes to making videos ( Other than: You probably would want to use a program that is popular ). Secondly Photoshop ( Creative suite ), Corel Painter ( 12 / other major versions. I guess sketch pad is some lite'ish version ) and Sketchbook ( Pro version. ) are all great at what they do. I think that the program that you would use to make the video is what might make the most difference here.

Comment: @Joonas - I'll be using Camtasia for screen recording.

Comment: It's funny because now I don't know what to say. Well, You might want to give Screenflow a try. I have used both, but I can't remember which was better. Camtasia _for mac_ has not been around as long as screenflow, but camtasia has been around a long time in windows. I can't seem to find a way to answer your question.

Comment: @Joonas - I'm using a PC

Comment: I know. I was just testing you... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article tells what Khan Academy uses for their screencast presentations](http://www.labnol.org/internet/khan-academy-style-videos/19875/):

1. Initially, Sal used Screen Video Recorder + MS Paint.
2. Now, he uses Camtasia Studio + Smooth Draw.

Despite what the article implies, he most likely used a Bamboo or similar tablet for all of the videos.

But I would still recommend using something that is more like a slideshow/presentation format. Sketchbook would work well since:

- It supports all the basic drawing/whiteboard-type functions with very natural-looking brushes and pencils, markers, etc.
- It supports layers, so you can easily group doodles/sketches and edit/remove them individually.
- It has a ruler/compass tool and grid lines that can help you draw charts and graphs.
- You can navigate across different documents in a manner similar to a slide deck.
- It's got a very simple/light-weight/intuitive interface.

Comment: Mac users: In lieu of SmoothDraw, Autodesk Sketchbook Express works (free with a Wacom): https://support.khanacademy.org/hc/en-us/articles/202483430-What-software-program-equipment-is-used-to-make-Khan-Academy-videos-